# vstest.console.exe randomly misses some tests

Tags: vstest

I am setting up unit tests to be executed on a build server (Jenkins).

I have noticed that sometimes vstest decides to ignore some of my tests. They are not skipped or failed. They are simply ignored as if they weren't there to begin with. I run the test build again without any changes and the problem goes away.

- There does not seem to be vstest crashes in the console log. It looks like the test run has completed normally, just with the wrong number of total tests.
- I checked the test assembly with a decompiler and all the test methods are there.
- TRX output file looks complete and valid.

In the trend graph below, red is failed, blue is passed. Notice the dip at #78? That's where I'm missing 3 out of 13 tests:

[image]

And here are vstest summaries from two consecutive builds, with no changes in between:

**#78:** `Total tests: 10. Passed: 6. Failed: 4. Skipped: 0.`

**#79:** `Total tests: 13. Passed: 9. Failed: 4. Skipped: 0.`

Did anybody encounter something like this? Should I consider ditching vstest in favor of a more reliable testing framework before I get too deeply entrenched in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about the bug. This is a regression in VS 2015. I fixed this bug in January and the fix will be included in VS 2015 Update 2. (I'm a software engineer at Microsoft.) The tests are actually run, but the results were sent back asynchronously and sometimes we closed the test host process before all of the results were sent back to the test engine process.

Comment: I have a simmilar issue. Running test project with 113 tests, but only 72 get found (16 fail / 52 pass). Do the results of the other thests get lost? How to make them not get lost? Only 72 test results are in the .TRX file, but not 113. If i increase timeout, the results stay the same.

Comment: if possible, could you please have a look at a similar question. [TFS Not all tests are run although the build is green](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36680473/2772330)